# Event.create in f#?

Tags: events, f#

I'm trying to compile the source code from : [Custom WPF Controls in F#](http://wpffsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest)

How ever this line :

```
 let (handler, event) = Event.create<EventArgs>()
```

raises an error :

`The value, constructor, namespace or type 'create' is not defined`

The [MSDN's Control.Event Module (F#) page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233189.aspx) does speak about such a function :

> The additional functionality provided by the Event module is
>   illustrated here. The following code example illustrates the basic use
>   of **Event.create** to create an event and a trigger method, add two
>   event handlers in the form of lambda expressions, and then trigger the
>   event to execute both lambda expressions.
>
> ```
> type MyType() =
>    let myEvent = new Event<_>()
>
>    member this.AddHandlers() =
>       Event.add (fun string1 -> printfn "%s" string1) myEvent.Publish
>       Event.add (fun string1 -> printfn "Given a value: %s" string1) myEvent.Publish
>
>    member this.Trigger(message) =
>       myEvent.Trigger(message)
>
> let myMyType = MyType()
> myMyType.AddHandlers()
> myMyType.Trigger("Event occurred.")
> ```

However note that it's only mentionned in the description, not in the example.

Also, the [Control.Event Module (F#) page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233189.aspx) has no reference to such a `create` function.

I guess it might be an old function or something, but I'm new to F# so I can't see what it should be replaced with..

Comment: My guess is it's been replaced with `new Event<'T>()`.

Comment: Maybe the docs are outdated. What should the line do, why is there a tuple pattern? Events are fairly simple in F#, see [their MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233189.aspx) for a quick introduction. ("Creating custom events" should be relevant)

Answer (score 8):

`Event.create` is a fairly old API for events, from before F# 2.0 judging by what's on MSDN. It gave you a trigger function and a published event - both of which now live as `Publish` and `Trigger` members of `Event` class.

So if you wanted to implement `create` in the 'modern' terms, it might look somewhat like this:

```
module Event = 
    let create<'T> () = 
        let event = Event<'T>()
        event.Trigger, event.Publish
```

I don't suggest you use it universally, but perhaps that's good enough to bring that old code back to life (the correct approach here being refactoring it to use `Publish` and `Trigger` instead of `create`).